# how to calculate difference between two LocalTime and save in the variable to be saved in the bank?

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, spring-data-jpa, localtime

I'm setting up a system where the user will insert the time of entry and the time of departure of an event (action) and when he gives the post my system would calculate the difference between the two times and save in a variable duration . I can't see how to do it so I tried it that way

@PrePersist
public Acao calculoDiferenca() {

```
    LocalDateTime inicio = LocalDateTime.of(entrada.getYear(), entrada.getMonth(), entrada.getDayOfMonth(),
            entrada.getHour(), entrada.getMinute(), entrada.getSecond());
    LocalDateTime fim = LocalDateTime.of(saida.getYear(), saida.getMonth(), saida.getDayOfMonth(), saida.getHour(),
            saida.getMinute(), saida.getSecond());
    Duration duration = Duration.between(inicio, fim);
    duracao = duration;
    
    System.out.println(duration);
    System.out.println("Days between " + inicio + "e" + fim + ":" + duration.toHours());

    return this;

}
```

then how would it be calculated to be saved in the variable duration and then be saved in the bank?

I think it would be better LocalDateTime because I may have a problem since there will be events that pass from one day to the next? for example: start on 2021-02-02 23:55:32 end on 2021-02-03 00:02:21

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Callback methods annotated on the bean class must return void and take no arguments: javax.persistence.PrePersist - public br.com.lucas.entity.Acao br.com.lucas.entity.Acao.calculoDiferenca()
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1788) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
```

if you need to look at more parts follow my code:
https://github.com/Akssasori/ApiRestfull-Merchandising

Comment: You haven't mentioned what you want to do with `diff`.

Comment: would put the diff within duration for it to be saved in the bank

Comment: You can use `duracao.toHoursPart()`, `duracao.toMinutesPart()`, and `duracao.toSecondsPart()` to get the hour, minute and second respectively.

Answer (score 0):

You can use`localDateOne.toEpochDay() - localDateTwo.toEpochDay();` for getting difference betweeen dates (in long).
And then you can get Locadate from difference:

```
LocalDate.ofEpochDay(localDateOne.toEpochDay() - localDateTwo.toEpochDay());
```

Comment: but in this case I only need the difference in hours, minutes and seconds

Answer (score 0):

Such method is present in `Duration` class itself:

```
Duration duration = Duration.between(inicio, fim);
```

Comment: yes but for this calculation to be done after the post and then without being saved in the bank as you would, like a pre-save you know?